# How to insert tikzpicture in beamer?

Tags: beamer, errors

I want to run this slide in `beamer`. I tried lot of things but always getting the errors for package clashes.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=blue}

\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{bibentry} 
\usepackage{color}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage {xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,epsfig,setspace,subfig,url,amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[all]{xypic}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bm}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

% New packages


%\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\tiny\raise1.5pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}}
% Or whatever. Note that the encoding and the font should match. If T1
% does not look nice, try deleting the line with the fontenc.
     \begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \tikzset{
      basic/.style  = {draw, text width=2cm, drop shadow,  rectangle},
      root/.style   = {basic, thin, align=center,
                   fill=gray!45 , text width=7em},
      level 2/.style = {basic, thin,align=center, fill=gray!30,
                   text width=7em},
      level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, fill=gray!20, text width=7em, node distance = 40pt}
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      level 1/.style={sibling distance=40mm},
      edge from parent/.style={->,draw},
      >=latex]

    % root of the the initial tree, level 1
    \node[root] {BRD1 ($\alpha_{..},\beta_{..}$)}
    % The first level, as children of the initial tree
      child {node[level 2] (c1) {$(\alpha_{..},\beta_{i.})$}}
      child {node[level 2] (c2) {$ (\alpha_{.j},\beta_{..})$}}
      child {node[level 2] (c3) { $(\alpha_{..},\beta_{.j})$}}
      child {node[level 2] (c4) { $(\alpha_{i.},\beta_{..})$}};

    % The second level, relatively positioned nodes
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={level 3}]
    \node [below of = c1, xshift=20pt] (c11) { $(\alpha_{i.},\beta_{i.})$};
    \node [below of = c11 ] (c12) {BRD9 $(\alpha_{.j},\beta_{i.})$};
    %\node [below of = c12] (c13) {$(\alpha_{..},\beta_{i.})$};

    \node [below of = c2, xshift=20pt] (c21) { $(\alpha_{.j},\beta_{.j})$};
    \node [below of = c21 ] (c22) {BRD9 $(\alpha_{.j},\beta_{i.})$};

    \node [below of = c3, xshift=20pt] (c31) { $(\alpha_{.j},\beta_{.j})$};
    \node [below of = c31 ] (c32) {BRD8 $(\alpha_{i.},\beta_{.j})$};

    \node [below of = c4, xshift=20pt] (c41) { $(\alpha_{i.},\beta_{i.})$};
    \node [below of = c41 ] (c42) { $(\alpha_{i.},\beta_{.j})$};

    %\node [below of = c2, yshift=-15pt, xshift=10pt] (c21) {Membership driven Re-Keying};
    %\node [below of = c21] (c22) {Time driven Re-Keying};

    %\node [below of = c3, xshift=15pt] (c31) {Ring-based Cooperation};
    %\node [below of = c31] (c32) {Hierarchical Cooperation};
    %\node [below of = c32] (c33) {Broadcast Cooperation};
    \end{scope}

    % lines from each level 1 node to every one of its "children"
    \foreach \value in {1,2}
      \draw[->] (c1.195) |- (c1\value.west);

    \foreach \value in {1,2}
      \draw[->] (c2.195) |- (c2\value.west);

    \foreach \value in {1,2}
      \draw[->] (c3.195) |- (c3\value.west);
    \foreach \value in {1,2}
      \draw[->] (c4.195) |- (c4\value.west);

    \end{tikzpicture}\\
    %\caption{Schematic Presentation of BRD models~\citep{Jansen05} } 
    \end{figure}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make this in to a complete document demonstrating the problem, so we can see which packages you are loading already.

Comment: What Andrew mentioned is a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `tikz` code needs the `shadows` library, so you should add

```
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
```

to your preamble.  The error message produce says thet `drop shadow` is not known.  Looking up `drop shadow` in the `pgfmanual`, e.g. via `texdoc pgfmanual` or `texdoc tikz` shows that it is part of the `shadows` library.

Now you need to adjust the size of your diagram...EDIT: I give one way to do this reducing a number of the fixed horizontal parameters you had:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \tikzset{
      basic/.style  = {draw, text width=5em, drop shadow,  rectangle},
      root/.style   = {basic, thin, align=center,
                   fill=gray!45 , text width=5em},
      level 2/.style = {basic, thin,align=center, fill=gray!30,
                   text width=5em},
      level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, fill=gray!20, text
      width=5em, node distance = 40pt} 
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      level 1/.style={sibling distance=30mm},
      edge from parent/.style={->,draw},
      >=latex]

    % root of the the initial tree, level 1
    \node[root] {BRD1 ($\alpha_{..},\beta_{..}$)}
    % The first level, as children of the initial tree
      child {node[level 2] (c1) {$(\alpha_{..},\beta_{i.})$}}
      child {node[level 2] (c2) {$ (\alpha_{.j},\beta_{..})$}}
      child {node[level 2] (c3) { $(\alpha_{..},\beta_{.j})$}}
      child {node[level 2] (c4) { $(\alpha_{i.},\beta_{..})$}};

    % The second level, relatively positioned nodes
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={level 3}]
    \node [below of = c1, xshift=10pt] (c11) { $(\alpha_{i.},\beta_{i.})$};
    \node [below of = c11 ] (c12) {BRD9 $(\alpha_{.j},\beta_{i.})$};
    %\node [below of = c12] (c13) {$(\alpha_{..},\beta_{i.})$};

    \node [below of = c2, xshift=10pt] (c21) { $(\alpha_{.j},\beta_{.j})$};
    \node [below of = c21 ] (c22) {BRD9 $(\alpha_{.j},\beta_{i.})$};

    \node [below of = c3, xshift=10pt] (c31) { $(\alpha_{.j},\beta_{.j})$};
    \node [below of = c31 ] (c32) {BRD8 $(\alpha_{i.},\beta_{.j})$};

    \node [below of = c4, xshift=10pt] (c41) { $(\alpha_{i.},\beta_{i.})$};
    \node [below of = c41 ] (c42) { $(\alpha_{i.},\beta_{.j})$};

    %\node [below of = c2, yshift=-15pt, xshift=10pt] (c21) {Membership driven Re-Keying};
    %\node [below of = c21] (c22) {Time driven Re-Keying};

    %\node [below of = c3, xshift=15pt] (c31) {Ring-based Cooperation};
    %\node [below of = c31] (c32) {Hierarchical Cooperation};
    %\node [below of = c32] (c33) {Broadcast Cooperation};
    \end{scope}

    % lines from each level 1 node to every one of its "children"
    \foreach \value in {1,2}
      \draw[->] (c1.195) |- (c1\value.west);

    \foreach \value in {1,2}
      \draw[->] (c2.195) |- (c2\value.west);

    \foreach \value in {1,2}
      \draw[->] (c3.195) |- (c3\value.west);
    \foreach \value in {1,2}
      \draw[->] (c4.195) |- (c4\value.west);

    \end{tikzpicture}\\
    %\caption{Schematic Presentation of BRD models~\citep{Jansen05} } 
    \end{figure}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You guys are the best....I was also just wondering is it possible to write this code in another file and compile it with my original ongoing file ?   I am having a huge code for my presentation and I want to write these codes in another file but still compile it with my original one

Comment: You can always put in a file `file.tex` and say `\input{file.tex}`.  See also the `standalone` package.